# Space Complexity of a Recursion Function Involving Additional Self-Contained Auxiliary Space

Tags: python, data-structures, big-o, space-complexity

I apologize for the poor wording of the question, but it seems that there is no other way to phrase it. Suppose we have the following code, which is just toy code to highlight my concern:

```
def dfs(root, seen):
  if not root:
    return seen
  
  seen.add(root)
  new_set = set(seen)

  dfs(root.left, new_set)
  dfs(root.right, new_set)
```

My question is regarding auxiliary space complexity. Typically, when dealing with recursion, the only auxiliary space complexity that needs to be considered is the space occupied on the call stack. However, in this case, we also see that within each function call, a new set is instantiated. In the worst case, this new set will have `H` elements, where `H` is the height of the tree. In this way, there will at worst be `H` function calls on the call stack, each of these calls containing a set of at worst `H` elements. Therefore, would the auxiliary space complexity be `O(H^2)`?

Comment: How large is `seen` in the top call?

Comment: It would likely be called with an empty set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the auxiliary space would be O(ℎ²).

First of all, I think the *intent* of your code is that for a given root node, both recursive calls (going left versus going right) get a `new_set` that has the *same* members. But this is not true because these recursive calls will add another member to it before it gets cloned. And so the second of these recursive calls will now have *two* more members than `seen` had at the top of this function call. I'll first assume this effect was not intended, so modify the code to first clone and then add:

```
def dfs(root, seen):
  if not root:
    return seen
  
  new_set = set(seen)
  new_set.add(root)

  dfs(root.left, new_set)
  dfs(root.right, new_set)
```

With this adapted code, there will at a certain moment be ℎ sets that are in use -- one for each distinct recursion depth -- with sizes 1, 2, 3, ..., ℎ, which is a [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF), and is indeed O(ℎ²).

Not your question, but this can be reduced to O(ℎ) if you keep using the same set, like so:

```
def dfs(root, seen):
  if not root:
    return seen
  
  seen.add(root)

  dfs(root.left, seen)
  dfs(root.right, seen)

  seen.remove(root)
```

But if the original code you had was intended to work like that, then the sets might grow with steps of 2, giving set sizes of 1, 3, 5, ..., 2ℎ+1, which is still O(ℎ²).

Comment: The sets can become larger than `H`, though. (I assume with h you mean `H`? Why rename?)

Comment: Yes, they can become twice as large due to what I think may be an unintentional twist in the asker's code (but maybe it was intentional): I have extended my answer.

Comment: Their code is quite strange, yes. Also strange that they put the nodes into a set. A list seems more appropriate: less memory, faster, and keeps order. Unless they have nodes that are equal (which is weird), in which case your O(h) version is btw wrong, as the `remove` can remove a node that also appears earlier in the path from the top so it should still remain in the set.

Comment: They wont have nodes that are equal, since they state it is a tree. The code does nothing useful, and so also the set is useless, but they call this "toy code", so I suppose in reality they have some use for the set.

Comment: Tree nodes can be equal, it would just be weird.

Comment: Please clarify @Kelly. In my understanding that would mean that a node can be reached via two different root-to-node paths (and a specific case where such a path could have multiple occurrences of that same node): this violates the notion of a tree, where two distinct nodes have only one path between them.

Comment: I don't mean the same node twice. I mean **two** equal nodes. Equality isn't identity. All you need for two nodes to be equal is an `__eq__` method that returns `True`. (And to match in the set, also a `__hash__` method returning the same hash for both nodes.)

Comment: Oh, OK, that way. As the asker hadn't provided such implementation, I had assumed the default object identity.